# Ext group of $k$ in the category of graded modules over the exterior algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and consider the exterior algebra 
$$\Lambda^{\bullet} k = k \oplus k\{1\}$$ 
where $k$ is seen as a vector space over itself. Consider the abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ of graded modules over $\Lambda^{\bullet}k$. 
I would like to compute 
$${\rm{Ext}}_{\mathcal{A}}^{i}(k,k \{j\})$$ 
where $\{ j\}$ denotes the shift of the grading of a module.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What graded module structure do you put on $k$ and $k\{j\}$?

Comment: $k$ is concentrated in degree $0$, and thus $k\{j\}$ is concentrated in degree $j$.

Comment: Does that mean that the $k\{1\}$ component of $\Lambda^\bullet k$ acts trivially in both cases?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: What have you tried so far?